# Clear a part of a text in a textbox with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox that have the following value:

```
The person 'enter name here' has finished.
```

I want if the user clicked on every where between `''` the text `enter name here` clear.
How to do this?

```
<input type="text" id="txt"/>
```

Edit:
I may have two or more place in a textbox.
like this:

```
The person 'enter name here','enter family here' has finished.
```

Comment: I misread your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly I would use jquery like so

```
<div>
    The Person <input type="text" value="'Enter Name Here'" /> has finished
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').focus(function() {
        $(this).val(""); 
    });

    $('input').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val("'Enter Name Here'");   
        }
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bExSy/

You can style the text box any way you would like it to look with the text

Answer (score -1):

You could make a fake textbox:

```
<div class="textbox">
    <div class="before">The person</div>
    <input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="enter name here" size="11" />
    <div class="after">has finished.</div>
</div>
```

And then (crudely) style it to look like a real one:

```
.textbox {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
}

input, div.before, div.after {
    display: inline-block;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3HEQj/**

I personally wouldn't use a textbox for this. If you don't care about accessibility, you can make a pop-out textbox that comes up when the user clicks on the text and then goes away afterwards.

Comment: I am thinking to find the text 'enter name here' in textbox and select it and remove it but I dont know how?